# How prevent `display-buffer` from opening a specific buffer in a new window if and only if it is shown in another frame

Tags: frames, window-splitting

I want the `*compilation*` buffer to *not* pop up in my main frame when I have it in another frame already open. However if the buffer is not shown anywhere, I do want it to pop up in a new window of the main frame.

I have set `special-display-regexps`:

```
(setq special-display-regexps (list "\\*compilation\\*.*"))
```

And this somewhat works: The compilation buffer does not open in a new window when it's displayed in another frame, so far so good, *but*, if it is not displayed anywhere it is opened in a brand new frame - and I do not want this.

Any idea how I can tweak this?

Comment: Here is a link to a semi-related thread where I target a specific frame for buffers matching a particular criteria, creating the frame if it does not already exist.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame  You would need a custom function to meet your specified criteria outlined in the question above.  Here is a link to a custom `my-display-buffer` function to target a specific window within a frame or create a new window (there are 3 built-in conditions).... https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/15118/2287

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but some info that might help.

You will likely need to fiddle with `display-buffer-alist` (good luck!). Someone here will no doubt help with that.

You cannot use `special-display-regexps` or `special-display-buffer-names` alone to do what you want - they're designed for the simple behavior you described: use (and reuse) an existing window, and if there is none then use a new frame.

A poor man's workaround would be to first create a `*compilation*` window on your "main" frame, and then do the `special-display-*` thing. If a window showing the buffer already exists somewhere (anywhere) then it will be reused. If such a window does not exist then the buffer will be displayed in a new frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```el
;; Prefer existing frames already displaying *compilation*.
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             (cons "\\`\\*compilation\\*\\'"
                   (cons 'display-buffer-reuse-window
                         '((reusable-frames . visible)
                           (inhibit-switch-frame . nil)))))
```

For more information, refer to:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `display-buffer-reuse-window`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `display-buffer-alist`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Displaying Buffers`

Comment: Wow, this looks proomising! Will try it out and report back. Thanks heaps!

Comment: How did you get on, @halloleo ?